# Filtering occurence records based on raster 0.5 resolution in R

Tags: r, raster, point, terra

I have a species "xy" data frame, for example:

```
points <- data.frame(Long = runif(100, min = -92, max = -88),
                    Lat = runif(100, min = 21.3, max = 25.5))
```

What I want is to filter the points based on a raster with an 0.5° resolution, leaving only one point inside every cell. First, I try to create an 0.5 resolution raster with the same extent of my points (minimum and maximum)

```
rast_05 <- rast(ext(min(points$Long), max(points$Long), 
                    min(points$Lat), max(points$Lat)), 
                    resolution = c(0.5, 0.5))
```

But when I plot the raster it does not have grids

```
plot(rast_05)
```

Comment: You've made a raster, just not assigned any values to the cells...so nothing to plot. Look at, first, simply `>rast_05`, then try `values(rast_05) = 1:ncell(rast_05)`, `plot(rast_05)`, and you see, you've made a raster, populated it with values, plotted it, and Welcome to Stackoverflow..